# Not getting proper result with my recursion for quick sum recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a string of digits, find the minimum number of additions required for the string to equal some target number. Each addition is the equivalent of inserting a plus sign somewhere into the string of digits.

example:
"1110"

target 3

return 3 as 1+1+1+0=3 requires 3 additions.

"0123456789"

target 45

Returns: 8

"99999"

target 100

Returns: -1

"382834"

100

Returns: 2

There are 3 ways to get 100. They are 38+28+34, 3+8+2+83+4 and 3+82+8+3+4. The minimum required is 2.

I tried this problem and here is my code. I am considering one character first time and getting the result. Next time i am using 2 characters and getting the result and so on until i tried all the characters up to the size of the string.I am not getting the recursion right.

```
    int min(int a,int b)
    {
        return a>b?b:a;
    }

    /* i is current index we are considering and sum is total number
     *of + required
     */
    int foo(char *a, int size, int i, int current_stock, int target, int sum){
        unsigned long long int mini = 1 << 30; /* huge number */
        int number=0, mul, m;
        int p = i;
        if (i+current_stock>size)
            return mini;
        if (target == 0)
            return sum;
        if (target < 0)
            return mini;
        mul = 1;
        /* make the multiplier */
        for (m=1;m<current_stock;m++) {
            mul *= 10;
        }
        /* make the number from i to current_stock
         * if the string is 123 and if i is 0 and current_stock is 2
         * then the number will be 12 */
        for (m=0;m<current_stock;m++) {
            number += (a[p]-'0')*mul;
            mul = mul/10;
            p++;
        }

        sum = sum + 1;
        for(m=current_stock;m<=size;m++) {
            mini = min(mini, foo (a, size, i+current_stock, m, target-number, sum));
        }
        return mini;
    }

    int main(void) {
        char a[] = "382834";
        printf("%d", foo(a, strlen(a), -1, 1, 100, 0));
        printf("%d\n", strlen(a));
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded up the exact solution you mentioned and it seems to be working for me. Just one change, You don't need to go till all the characters, if you have crossed target then can break early.

```
#define INFINITY 100000
long int result[20][1000];

long int solve(char *str,long int i,long int target){
    long int min=INFINITY;
    long int number=0,base=10;
    long int j=i;
    long int score1;
    //memoized result
    if(result[i][target]!=-2){
        return result[i][target];
    }

    //if target is achieved and string is finished
    if(i==strlen(str) && target==0){
        return 0;
    }
    // if string finished but target not achieved
    if(i==strlen(str)&& target!=0){
        return -1;
    }

    while(j<strlen(str)){
        long int digit=str[j]-'0';
        number=number*base+digit;
        if(number <=target){
            score1=solve(str,j+1,target-number);
            if(score1!=-1){
                if(j<(strlen(str)-1))
                    score1=score1+1;
                if(score1<min){
                    min=score1;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(min<INFINITY)
        result[i][target]=min;
    else
        result[i][target] = -1;
    return result[i][target];
}
```

I am initializing my memoized array result with -2 for non calculated values. I checked with all the gives test cases and it is working. Please checkout the solution and let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Your solution is almost similar to mine so i am marking this as correct solution. Solution posted by Gene is perfect but since your solution is similar to mine i am marking this as correct answer.

Comment: @newbie_old Thanks. By the way, is it a spoj (or any other online judge) problem? Can you please share the link if so?

Answer (score 1):

I guess @Naman got you to a solution, but you are working way too hard. Just place the first plus in each possible position and then recur to place the rest.  The base case is when all the digits are equal to the target. In this case, the number of plusses required is zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NO_SOLUTION (-1)

int find_min_plusses(int target, char *digits, int n_digits) {
  int min = NO_SOLUTION, val = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; i < n_digits - 1; i++) {
    val = val * 10 + (digits[i] - '0');
    if (val > target) return min;
    int rest = find_min_plusses(target - val, digits + i + 1, n_digits - i - 1);
    if (rest != NO_SOLUTION && (min == NO_SOLUTION || rest + 1 < min))
      min = rest + 1;
  }
  val = val * 10 + (digits[i] - '0');
  return val == target ? 0 : min;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int target;
  if (argc == 3) {
    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &target) != 1) return 1;
    int min = find_min_plusses(target, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
    printf("%d\n", min);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here you can watch it run. Each line is a call.

```
./a.out 100 382834
tgt=100,digits=382834,n_digits=6
tgt=97,digits=82834,n_digits=5
tgt=89,digits=2834,n_digits=4
tgt=87,digits=834,n_digits=3
tgt=79,digits=34,n_digits=2
tgt=76,digits=4,n_digits=1
tgt=4,digits=4,n_digits=1
tgt=61,digits=34,n_digits=2
tgt=58,digits=4,n_digits=1
tgt=15,digits=834,n_digits=3
tgt=7,digits=34,n_digits=2
tgt=4,digits=4,n_digits=1
tgt=62,digits=2834,n_digits=4
tgt=60,digits=834,n_digits=3
tgt=52,digits=34,n_digits=2
tgt=49,digits=4,n_digits=1
tgt=34,digits=34,n_digits=2
tgt=31,digits=4,n_digits=1
2
```

Comment: very crafty code and it is perfect but this is not the solution to the problem I was facing as i was looking for a code which is similar to mine.

Comment: @newbie_old Sure.  That's as may be. I just wanted you to know you were solving the problem in a rather round-about way. My code isn't crafty at all. It's a straightforward way to arrange the recursion.